# Ubuntu Virtualbox: VM of running how to switch to headless VM

Tags: virtualbox

Ubuntu Virtualbox
I have a VM already start normally and connnected local screen,
now is there any way to switch VM mode to headlesss,
that will make window backend and no more cost for rendering window
?

Comment: You may want to look at the following site: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-run-virtualbox-virtual-machines-from-the-command-line/

Comment: Why not use multipass or even better lxd?

Comment: You can't switch to headless but you can easily start: `vboxmanage startvm <vmname> --type headless`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just take any running VM in VirtualBox and make it go headless.  You can, however, start your VM in **Detachable Start** that will allow you to detach from the GUI after doing whatever configurations or launching of applications in your VM.

[image]

Then choose **Machine -> Detach GUI** and your VM will basically now be in a headless mode:

[image]

Hope this helps!